# Strange error output when I have mixed types,Scala

Tags: scala

```
Error:(21, 39) type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: _1 where type _1 >: Int with Float <: AnyVal
      varsMap(name) enqueue bar.intMap(name)
```

varsMap is a map with keys of string and values are Queues which elements can be Int or Float depending on maps keys

So varsMap("int1") is mutable.Queue[Int]

And varsMap("float1") is mutable.Queue[Float]

bar.intMap(name) has an integer value

I don't understand this notation: **required: _1 where type _1 >: Int with Float <: AnyVal**

Can someone explain shortly what does it mean?

Addition of the parts of the code:

```
 val integerSet = immutable.Set("int1","int2","int3")
  val floatSet = immutable.Set("float1","float2","float3","float4")
  val indicatorSet = immutable.Set("source", "ave", "range")
  //creating the map of data
  var varsMap = (integerSet map (t => t -> new mutable.Queue[Int]) toMap) ++ (floatSet map (t => t -> new mutable.Queue[Float]) toMap) ++ (indicatorSet map (t => t -> new mutable.Queue[Float]) toMap)
```

and then there is the part when error is displayed

```
varsMap("int1") enqueue 5 //for example try to insert number 5
```

so it cant get that value cos it expects some strange type: _1 where type _1 >: Int with Float <: AnyVal

Comment: How did you construct varsMap?

Comment: @Kraylog like this: **var varsMap = (integerSet map (t => t -> new mutable.Queue[Int]) toMap) ++ (floatSet map (t => t -> new mutable.Queue[Float]) toMap) ++ (indicatorSet map (t => t -> new mutable.Queue[Float]) toMap)** <br> I'm sure it is not a proper way but I want to know exactly why and how should I deal with this

Comment: @Kraylog integerSet = immutable.Set("int1","int2","int3") and similar for others

Comment: Oh, so `integerSet` is a set of strings?

Comment: I think sharing more of your code would make it much easier to understand and help you. Please add it to the question, and not in a comment.

Comment: @Kraylog ok, will do it

Comment: By reading your question, I think you want to build a Map which maps Strings to, for some values `Queue[Int]` and for some other values `Queue[Float]` (and this is your problem, you are mixing two different types). You should use `Either` to reflect that the result type could be any of those two, and the type of your map will look something like this: `Map[String, Either[Queue[Int], Queue[Float]]]`

Comment: @nicodp you mean to put **var varsMap: Map[String, Either[Queue[Int], Queue[Float]]]** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you to analyze the types of your intermediate collections step-by-step, e.g.

```
val m1 = (integerSet map (t => t -> new mutable.Queue[Int]) toMap)
val m2 = (floatSet map (t => t -> new mutable.Queue[Float]) toMap)
val m3 = (indicatorSet map (t => t -> new mutable.Queue[Float]) toMap)
```

So the types of those maps respectively are:

```
Map[String, Queue[Int]]
Map[String, Queue[Float]]
Map[String, Queue[Float]]
```

Then you are trying to merge all those maps:

```
var varsMap = m1 ++ m2 ++ m3
```

Finally you obtain a specific queue from that map you want to use:

```
val vmInt = varsMap("int1")
```

which has a type: `Queue[_ >: Int with Float <: AnyVal{def getClass(): Class[_ >: Int with Float <: AnyVal]}]`

which is essentially saying that the queue is intended to store values of **type which is subclass of AnyVal and superclass of a hybrid "Int with Float" type**.
It could be better illustrated by the following diagram:

[image]

So in given context underscore is a type of value which you want to put into your queue. As "Int with Float" is subclass of that type you also can put values of that type into queue. However it is not true for Int and Float values as Int and Float are not subclasses of _ type. That's why you have the error.

What you can actually do is to construct value of the type **Int with Float** and put it into your queue:

```
val i: Int with Float = 5.asInstanceOf[Int with Float]
varsMap("int1") enqueue i
```

but I don't think it is idiomatically correct and convenient for you to work with values of such type. I suggest instead to reconsider your logic so that you enqueue to any of specific maps m1, m2, m3.

Comment: Thank you! I already switched to that approach I just wanted to understand what happens there, and you explained it really nice